# Draggable/ multiple droppables in scrollable div issue

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable, droppable

I'm trying to use Jquery ui draggable and droppable libraries to achieve the following scenario [image]

There are multiple droppables inside a div with a scrollbar. The issue I'm getting is that whenever I scroll down in the droppables containing div, if I try to drag and drop an element it's being dropped in the top of the div (in a wrong droppable). If I remove the max-height limit (no more scroll bar) it works fine.
Is this a known issue or am I missing something?
Here is the code : addDroppable is called as many times as there are droppables
function addDroppable(elementId) {

```
$('#' + elementId).droppable({
   accept: '.myclassselector',
   activeClass: "drop-area",
   drop: function (e, ui) {
      x = ui.helper.clone();
      ui.helper.remove();
      x.appendTo($(this));
   }
});

$(".myclassselector").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    zIndex: 1,
    tolerance: 'fit',
    refreshPositions: true,
    revert: true
});
```